# jQuery, how can I make my puzzle game work on a touch screen device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Say I have a puzzle game,

```
// One function

document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;

// Another function           

document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
```

Example of puzzle clicking functions I have:

```
    function onPuzzleClick(e){

        if(e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
            _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
            _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0){
            _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
            _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
        }
```

**Another Part**

```
document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        if(_currentDropPiece != null){
            var tmp = {xPos:_currentPiece.xPos,yPos:_currentPiece.yPos};
            _currentPiece.xPos = _currentDropPiece.xPos;
            _currentPiece.yPos = _currentDropPiece.yPos;
            _currentDropPiece.xPos = tmp.xPos;
            _currentDropPiece.yPos = tmp.yPos;
        }
        resetPuzzleAndCheckWin();
    }
```

What is the best way to enable this puzzle for touch devices? 
Should I try and bind touch and mouse? 
Do I have to rewrite the conditional statements?

Any Ideas?

Comment: no need to use  any thing you can make it in a simple jquery or js i am sending you this type of game in my answer just check it and make like that one.

Answer (score 0):

It is full puzzle game code with css and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AnupPuzzle</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.main-container{background:#600; width:270px; height:270px; text-align:center;}
button{width:80px; height:80px; background:#CCC; float:left; margin:5px; color:#600; font-size:18px; }
button:hover{background:#9CF;}
span{width:100%; color:#900; font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Are you want to try your brain logics...</h3>
<div class="main-container">    
    <button alt="" name="1" value="1" id="1">5</button>
    <button alt="" name="2" value="2" id="2">6</button>
    <button alt="" name="3" value="3" id="3">8</button>
    <button alt="" name="4" value="4" id="4">3</button>
    <button alt="" name="5" value="5" id="5"></button>
    <button alt="" name="6" value="6" id="6">7</button>
    <button alt="" name="7" value="7" id="7">1</button>
    <button alt="" name="8" value="8" id="8">2</button>
    <button alt="" name="9" value="9" id="9">4</button>
</div>
<span>Anup</span>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var upval, downval, leftval, rightval, txt, bVal;
$("button").click(function(){
    txt = $(this).text();
    bVal = $(this).val();   
    if(txt != ""){
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 2) &&(bVal != 3)){
            upval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(3));           
            var upTxt = $("#"+upval).text();            
            if(upTxt == ""){            
                $("#"+upval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 7) && (bVal != 8) &&(bVal != 9)){
            downval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(3));            
            var downTxt = $("#"+downval).text();
            if(downTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+downval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 4) &&(bVal != 7)){
            leftval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(1));         
            var leftTxt = $("#"+leftval).text();
            if(leftTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+leftval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 3) && (bVal != 6) &&(bVal != 9)){
            rightval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(1));           
            var rightTxt = $("#"+rightval).text();          
            if(rightTxt == ""){                 
                $("#"+rightval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        var one = $("#1").text();
        var two = $("#2").text();
        var three = $("#3").text();
        var four = $("#4").text();
        var five = $("#5").text();
        var six = $("#6").text();
        var seven = $("#7").text();
        var eight = $("#8").text();
        var nine = $("#9").text();

        if((one == "1")&&(two == "2")&&(three == "3")&&(four == "4")&&(five == "5")&&(six == "6")&&(seven == "7")&&(eight == "8")&&(nine == "")){           
            alert("Congratulations You Won The Game...");
            $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }               
    }   
});

});


</script>
```

Comment: no need to use  any thing you can make it in a simple jquery or js i am sending you this type of game in my answer just check it and make like that one. It is simple 0-9 puzzle game keep your images at the place of numbers change it with your images as a background images of buttons. gud luk